# Install Sikuli in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, ide, automation, installation, sikuli

Is sudo apt-get install sikuli enough to install sikuli on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.
I could not find any instructions for 12.04 and 12.10. This is important to automate my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get install sikuli-ide` instead.

And, after a simple Google search I have found the following guides to Sikuli installation on Ubuntu:

1. [Link1](http://playingwithsid.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/installing-sikuli-automation-tool-on.html)
2. [Link2](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/sikuli-atomation-tool-using-images-100.html)
3. [Link3](http://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-lucid-lynx-linux-sikuli-installation)

Comment: I could install this but it could not run anything.